# How to refer to one output of multioutput model

Tags: keras, multipleoutputs, generative-adversarial-network

I have a multioutput network of the following form (yes, the code is mostly from the medium article: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/implementing-a-gan-in-keras-d6c36bc6ab5f)

```
input = Input(shape=(100,50),dtype='float32')
drop_1 = Dropout(0.3,name='drop_1')(input)
dense_1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(drop_1)
dense_2 = Dense(2)(dense_1)
flatten_1 = Flatten()(dense_2)
preds = Dense(7,activation='softmax')(flatten_1)

generator = Model(sequence_input, outputs=[preds,dense_2])
generator.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy',None],
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['acc'])
```

Now I want to use the output in another network (I am trying to build a GAN) but therefor need to use the second output as follows:

## Where I need the output:

```
gan_input = Input(shape=(100,50),dtype='float32')
fake = generator(gan_input)
gan_output = discriminator(fake[1])
```

How do I refer to it? fake[1] does not seem to work, it results in the following mistake:

```
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure the error is there? It seems to be another thing.

Comment: It seems that you are right, I was to focused on thinking that fake[1] must be the cause. Thank you!